# customize the sort function in R

Tags: r, sorting

I want to sort a vector containing ratings,

```
r<-c("A","AA","AAA","BBB","BB","B","CCC")
```

However, by applying `sort`

```
> sort(r)
[1] "A"   "AA"  "AAA" "B"   "BB"  "BBB" "CCC"
```

Is there any method which enables me to get the following

```
"AAA"   "AA"  "A" "BBB"   "BB"  "B" "CCC"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r <- c("A","AA","AAA","BBB","BB","B","CCC") 
r <- factor(r, levels = c("AAA","AA","A","BBB", "BB", "B", "CCC"))


sort(r)
# [1] AAA AA  A   BBB BB  B   CCC
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use factors and create levels as follows:

```
    r<-c("A","AA","AAA","BBB","BB","B","CCC")
    r <- factor(r, levels = c("AAA", "AA","A","BBB","BB","B","CCC"))
    sort(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option with `ave`

```
ave(r, substr(r, 1, 1), FUN = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE))
#[1] "AAA" "AA"  "A"   "BBB" "BB"  "B"   "CCC"
```