# Sort dataframe by custom order

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains a rating column.

I would like to sort using a custom order, e.g.
`AAA, AA, A, BBB, BB, B`

However, default R sorting (using `dplyr::arrange)` results in
`A AA AAA B BB BBB`

```
data.frame(Rating=c('AAA','AA','A','B','BB','BBB'),
           Value1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
           Value2=c(2,3,4,5,3,2)) %>% 
           arrange(Rating)
```

I found many links referring to same problem but they are not related to dataframe eg
[customize the sort function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52597882/customize-the-sort-function-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

How can I sort my data using a custom order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the column as character rather than factor, you can arrange based on a `match` to the order vector

```r
rating_order <- c("AAA", "AA", "A", "BBB", "BB", "B")

df <-
  data.frame(
    Rating = c("A", "AA", "AAA", "B", "BB", "BBB"),
    Value1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    Value2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2)
  )

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>%
  arrange(match(Rating, rating_order))
#>   Rating Value1 Value2
#> 1    AAA      3      4
#> 2     AA      2      3
#> 3      A      1      2
#> 4    BBB      6      2
#> 5     BB      5      3
#> 6      B      4      5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using `dplyr`.
In short, first sort by the letter grade, and then again by the number of letters. This would not work for ratings such as `AAB`, but from what I gather from your example this isn't the case.

```r
library(dplyr)

data.frame(Rating=c('AAA','AA','A','B','BB','BBB'),
           Value1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
           Value2=c(2,3,4,5,3,2)) %>%
  mutate(grade = substr(Rating, 1,1), # Create a column with letter grade
         count = nchar(Rating)) %>%   # Create a column with number of letters
  arrange(grade, count) %>%           # Sort by grade, then count
  select(-grade, count)               # Optional, removes intermediary columns

#>   Rating Value1 Value2 count
#> 1      A      3      4     1
#> 2     AA      2      3     2
#> 3    AAA      1      2     3
#> 4      B      4      5     1
#> 5     BB      5      3     2
#> 6    BBB      6      2     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you know the complete list of possible ratings, the easiest way is to make it a factor with the values in order, e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
data.frame(Rating=factor(c('A', 'AA','AAA','B','BB','BBB'),
                         levels=c('AAA','AA','A','BBB','BB','B')),
       Value1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
       Value2=c(2,3,4,5,3,2)) %>% 
       arrange(Rating)
#>   Rating Value1 Value2
#> 1    AAA      3      4
#> 2     AA      2      3
#> 3      A      1      2
#> 4    BBB      6      2
#> 5     BB      5      3
#> 6      B      4      5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>